# Arch modules not loading on start?

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, configuration, kernel-modules, x-server

I keep getting errors on startup in Arch relating to my `rc.conf`:

```
failed to load module "wl"
failed to load module "lib80211"
```

etc. It lists all the modules in my `/etc/rc.conf`

This is my full `rc.conf`:

```
#
# /etc/rc.conf - configuration file for initscripts
#

DAEMONS=(syslog-ng dbus networkmanager crond .. etc. ..)
MODULES=(... wl... lib80211... nvidia-bl... openntpd... slim... acpid... pommed)

# Storage
#
# USEDMRAID="no"
# USELVM="no"

# Network
#
# interface=
# address=
# netmask=
# gateway=

HARDWARECLOCK="UTC-5"
TIMEZONE="US/Central"
```

I notcied this when `pommed` failed to start in X when I added `sudo pommed &` in my `xinitrc`.

Is the config file formated properly?

Comment: What are the '...' in MODULES ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `rc.conf` is not properly configured; the elipses (`...`) in the wiki are illustrative only. The `rc.conf` file is a shell script and arrays shouldn't contain those dots.

Using that method is the deprecated way of loading modules. If you wish to continue to list them in this file, then you should use this format:

```
MODULES=(wl lib80211 nvidia-bl)
```

The correct way to load these modules is outlined on the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_modules#Configuration), by creating files under `/etc/modprobe.d/`. In the case of `wl`, as an example, you would create `/etc/modprobe.d/wl` and the file would contain:

```
# load broadcom module at boot
wl
```

Further, `openntpd` is a daemon, and should be listed in that array, not in the modules one—as should `slim` and `acpid`. I don't know what `pommed` is but I would check where that should be placed as well.

Comment: Okay, I got it working. The dots are what was messing me up. Thanks